# Sybase: is it possible to set @@error

Tags: sql, sybase, raiserror

Is it possible in Sybase to set global variable @@error = 0 for successfull return after raiserror statement?

```
raiserror 'Test';
set @@error = 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sybase ASE you can't directly set `@@error` or use `raiseerror` with a string.

Use `sp_addmessage` to add custom error numbers and messages to your database.  Once the error is listed, you can then reference it using the `raiserror error_#`

Sybase ASE reserves error numbers 20,000 and below for system use, so user defined errors can start at 20,001

More detailed information on [`raiserror` can be found in the documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1550/html/commands/X60573.htm).